# How to detect span changes in EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Is there any way to detect changes made to spans in `EditText` (in Android)?
A `TextWatcher` added to the EditText is notified only about text changes.
No support in `Editable`/`SpannableStringBuilder` too.
A workaround could be to have a fake `InputFilter` on the `Editable`, but obviously not ideal, and you never know if the change was actually applied.
Thanks.